Callback handlers in Langchain
This might be an odd question, but why is there two codes for the class BaseCallbackHandler?
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/_modules/langchain_core/callbacks/base.html#BaseCallbackHandler
https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/callbacks/

I think they are the same thing. If you look at the BaseCallbackHandler object definition in the first link, it is sub-classed from a bunch of mixins. The methods in the second link are defined in these mixins. For example, on_llm_start, the first method shown in the second link that BaseCallbackHandler defines, is inherited from CallbackManagerMixin (further up in the same documentation in the first link). All other methods are similarly inherited from each of these mixins.
